# $A \bigotimes \mathbb{Z}_m \cong \frac{A}{mA}$, I need help with tensors!

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

So, i'm just starting trying to understand tensor products. A basic exercise is given by showing the following equality:

$A \bigotimes \mathbb{Z}_m \cong \frac{A}{mA}$

Well, how about the map $\gamma(a,\bar{x})= ax$ mod $mA$.

And now i'm lost. Can anyone give me some insight please? Thanks!

Comment: $A \cong A \otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} \Bbb{Z}$ and the kernel of $A \otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} \Bbb{Z} \to A \otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} (\Bbb{Z}/m \Bbb{Z})$ is $A \otimes_{\Bbb{Z}}m \Bbb{Z}=m (A \otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} \Bbb{Z}) \cong mA$.

Comment: Could you prove $A \cong A \bigotimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Z}$ for me?

Comment: $\otimes_{\Bbb{Z}}$ is a bilinear symbol, in particular $a \otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} n = an \otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} 1$  and the multiplication is defined by $(a \otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} b)(c \otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} d) =ac \otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} bd$ thus $a \mapsto a \otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} 1$ is the isomorphism.